# gnuradio: how to change the noutput_items dynamically when writing OOT block?

Tags: python-2.7, signal-processing, gnuradio, modulation

When I make a OOT block in gnuradio

```
class mod(gr.sync_block):
"""
docstring for block mod
"""
def __init__(self):
    gr.sync_block.__init__(self,
        name="mod",
        in_sig=[np.byte],
        out_sig=[np.complex64])
def work(self, input_items, output_items):
    in0 = input_items[0]
    out = output_items[0]
    result=do(....)
    out[:]=result
    return len(output_items[0])
```

I get:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (122879) into shape (4096)
```

How can I solve it?
GRC is as below:
selector :input index  and output index are controlled by WX  GUI Chooser block
FSK4 MOD: modulate fsk4 signal and write data to raw.bin
FSK4 DEMOD : read data from raw.bin and demodulate

```
file source -> /////// -> FSK4 MOD -> FSK4 DEMOD -> NULL SINK
               selector 
file source -> //////  -> GMKS MOD -> GMSK DEMOD ->NULL SINK
```

when the input index or output index  is changed,the whole  flow graph will be not responding.

Comment: You have indentation problems.

Answer (score 4):

There's two things:

1. You have a bug somewhere, and the solution is not to change something, but fix that bug. The full Python error message will tell you exactly in which line the error is.
2. `noutput_items` is a variable that GNU Radio sets at runtime to let you know how much output you might produce in this call to `work`. Hence, it's not something you can *set*, but it's something your `work` method must *respect*.

I think it's fair to assume that you're not very aware of how GNU Radio works:

GNU Radio is based on calling your block's `work` function when there is enough output space available and enough input items to process. The amount of output space that your block can use is passed to your `work` as a parameter, and will change between calls to `work`.

I **very** strongly recommend going through chapters 1-3 of the  [**official Guided Tutorials**](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorials) if you haven't already. We always try to keep these tutorials up-to-date.

**EDIT**: Your command shows that you have not really understood what I meant, sorry. So: GNU Radio calls your `work` method over and over again while it's executing.

For example, it might call `work` with 4000 input items and 4000 output items space (you have a sync block, therefore number of input==number of output). Your `work` processes the first 1000 of that, and therefore `return 1000`. So there's 3000 items left.

Now, the upstream block does something, so there's 100 new items. Because the 3000 from before are still there, your block's `work` will get called with `3100` items.

Your `work` processes any number of items, and `return`s that number. GNU Radio makes sure that the "remaining" items stay available and will call your `work` again if there is enough in- our output.

Comment: Thank you! since I can't change the noutput_items,I write the output  to a file. (there are two blocks to modulate/demodulate 4fsk signal)  Well,when I stop the GRC that is dynamically  reading data from the modulated file,the whole flow graph is always not responding .I really don't know how to deal with these data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you misunderstand how (general_)work is supposed to be implemented, sorry.

Comment: There's been a downvote, which is democratically fine. But: I'm the GNU Radio maintainer. I'd be most interested in what is wrong about my answer, or in which way it's not answering OP's question.